# jQuery - How to loop the function?

Tags: jquery

I want to make a basic fadein fadeout slideshow.I only make it auto run once.
How to make it have a loop??

html

```
<img src="image1.jpg" class="img1">
<img src="image2.jpg" class="img2">
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
function playslider(){
        $('.img1').fadeIn(800).delay(800).fadeOut(800);
        $('.img2').delay(1600).fadeIn(800).delay(800).fadeOut(800);
}   
playslider();
});
```

Comment: you mean you want to autoplay it only once?

Comment: NO,I make it--> fadeOut(800, playslider).And how to I make last image fadeout and cross with the next first image fadein??

Answer (score 8):

Try changing it to this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
function playslider(){
        $('.img1').fadeIn(800).delay(800).fadeOut(800);
        $('.img2').delay(1600).fadeIn(800).delay(800).fadeOut(800, playslider);
                                                                 //^callback function
}   
playslider();
});
```

This is called a "callback function".  The idea is that it gets called when your last fadeout completes.  You can read more [here](http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works#Callback_and_Functions).

Comment: Thanks.How to I make last image fadeout and cross with the next first image fadein.

Comment: Cross fading is beyond the scope of your current question and would be difficult for me to answer in a comment.  I would recommend creating a new question for that particular problem.  I will say that in the past I have typically used a jQuery plugin to handle cross fading.

Answer (score 2):

You can use good old Javascript:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
 function playslider(){
      // code to execute
     x = setTimeout("playslider()", 5000); //will loop every 5 seconds.
 }   
 playslider(); //start it up the first time

 });
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 function playslider(){
      // code to execute
     x = setTimeout(function(){playslider()}, 5000);
 }   
 playslider();

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

it works good but if u change it in this way it works better

```
    $('.img1').fadeIn(800).delay(800).fadeOut(800);
    $('.img2').delay(2400).fadeIn(800).delay(800).fadeOut(800, playslider);
```

just increase dalay time to 2400(2400=800+800+800)